# Best performing way to guarantee data consistency between concurrent web service calls?

Tags: java, sql, database, multithreading, jakarta-ee

Multiple clients are concurrently accessing a JAX-JWS webservice running on Glassfish or some other application server. Persistence is provided by something like Hibernate or OpenJPA. Database is Microsoft SQL Server 2005.

The service takes a few input parameters, some "magic" occurs, and then returns what is basically a transformed version of the next available value in a sequence, with the particular sequence and transformation being determined by the inputs. The "magic" that performs the transformation depends on the input parameters and various database tables (describing the relationship between the input parameters, the transformation, the sequence to get the next base value from, and the list of already served values for a particular sequence). Not sure if this could all be wrapped up in a stored procedure (probably), but also not sure if the client wants it there.

What is the best way to ensure consistency (i.e. each value is unique and values are consumed in order, with no opportunity for a value to reach a client without also being stored in the database) while maintaining performance?

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to provide a complete answer without a full description (table schemas, etc.), but giving my best guess here as to how it works, I would say that you need a transaction around your "magic", which marks the next value in the sequence as in use before returning it. If you want to reuse sequence numbers then you can later unflag them (for example, if the user then cancels what they're doing) or you can just consider them lost.

One warning is that you want your transaction to be as short and as fast as possible, especially if this is a high-throughput system. Otherwise your sequence tables could quickly become a bottleneck. Analyze the process and see what the shortest transaction window is that will still allow you to ensure that a sequence isn't reused and use that.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have most of the elements you need here. One thing that might pose difficulty, depending on how you've implemented your service, is that you don't want to write any response to the browser until your database transaction has been safely committed without errors.

A lot of web frameworks keep the persistence session open (and uncommitted) until the response has been rendered to support lazy loading of persistent objects by the view. If that's true in your case, you'll need to make sure that none of that rendered view is delivered to the client until you're sure it's committed.

One approach is a Servlet `Filter` that buffers output from the servlet or web service framework that you're using until it's completed its work.